# Slashes removed from calls to File.mkdirs()

Tags: android, android-sdcard

As the title suggests, I am trying to create a folder on Android, but all of the slashes have been removed from it.

***For some more background information:***

Specifically, I am trying to create a directory to store my application's users' files. These files must be accessible to the user from a file manager (such as File Manager HD) because the application does not support full file management. Using the standard from API level 8+, I reference the root of the publicly accessible folder with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. I then try to create a folder located at **DCIM > Sketchbook > [the name of the sketch]** using `File.mkdirs()`. For more information, see the code below.

***I have already:***

- checked to make sure that the SD card is mounted, readable, and writable
- enabled the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
- tried using `File.mkdir()` for every file in the hierarchy up to the folder location
- tried using `/`, `\\`, `File.separatorChar`, and `File.separator` as folder separators

***Code:***

```
boolean success = true;

//The public directory
File publicDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
//The location of the sketchbook
File sketchbookLoc = new File(publicDir + "Sketchbook" + File.separator);
//The location of the sketch
//getGlobalState().getSketchName() returns the name of the sketch: "sketch"
File sketchLoc = new File(sketchbookLoc + getGlobalState().getSketchName() + File.separator);

if(!sketchLoc.mkdirs()) success = false;

//Notify the user of whether or not the sketch has been saved properly
if(success)
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(getResources().getText(R.string.sketch_saved));
else
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(getResources().getText(R.string.sketch_save_failure));
```

With various incarnations of the aforementioned tests (the ones that actually worked), I have received a consistent result: I get a new folder in DCIM whose name corresponds to the combination of all of the folders that should have been hierarchical parents of it. In other words, I have created a new directory, but all of the folder separators have been removed from it.

***Now, I ask you:***

- Am I attempting to save the user data in the correct location? Is there another way that I should be doing this?
- Is it even possible to create new folders in the DCIM folder? Does Android prevent it?
- Is this problem specific to me? Is anyone else able to create a folder in the DCIM folder?
- Am I using the right folder separators?
- Is there something else that I am absolutely, completely, and utterly missing?

Now that I am done typing, and you are done reading my (excessively long) question, I hope that I can find some sort of answer. If you need clarification or more information, please say so.

EDIT: An example of the created folder is "DCIMSketchbooksketch", where it should be "DCIM/Sketchbook/sketch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use

```
File sketchbookLoc = new File(publicDir + "Sketchbook" + File.separator);
```

but

```
File sketchbookLoc = new File(publicDir , "Sketchbook");
```

because publicDir.toString() will **not** end with a file separator (even if you declared it that way). toString() gives the canonical name of the file.

---

So your source becomes :

```
//The location of the sketchbook
File sketchbookLoc = new File(publicDir , "Sketchbook" );
//The location of the sketch
File sketchLoc = new File(sketchbookLoc , getGlobalState().getSketchName() );
```

Comment: This was exactly the sort of trick that I was looking for... thank you!